# Turning off list attachments deletes all existing attachments--Can I recover any of these files?

Tags: list, attachments, recycle-bin

Turning off a list's attachments deletes all existing attachments--Can I recover any of these files after turning off the attachments feature?

They don't seem to go to the recycle bin when you turn off the feature at the list level.

Comment: Do we have new answer on the same question? Can we recover deleted SharePoint List Attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attachments will be gone. There is no solution that I know of to get them back unless you are willing to contact Microsoft for a complete restore of the site.